# prevent page from reloading after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, reload

Is there a way to detect and stop if page is reloading.

I have a page which is getting reloaded after successful submission of a form present in it. I want to have an event listener which sees if page is reloading and should stop it from being reloaded.

I cannot `return false;` for sucessful submit of registration form

Comment: What do you want? Do you want the form to submit, but the page to not change/leave?

Answer (score 12):

In your html:

```html
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
    Enter name: <input type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In your javascript:

```js
myFunction = function(e) {
    // prevents default action to happen
    e.preventDefault();
    // do what ever you want to do here
    // i.e. perform a AJAX call
}
```

Comment: For this to work you have to pass the event when calling the function, like this: `<form onsubmit="myFunction(event)">`

Answer (score 2):

You would have to submit the form using AJAX to avoid refreshing the entire page.

This can be accomplished with regular Javascript but is made easier with jQuery
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Detecting if the page is reloading is a very dirty solution.

You have to prevent the default action

```
<script>
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 1):

In that case you'll need to implement the form sending mechanics via some kind of AJAX call.

Because sending a form is actually loading a new page with some parameters (which are the form data).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how a standard form submission works:

```
Browser -> issues GET or POST HTTP request -> Server
Browser <- returns the result of the request <- Server
Browser re-renders the current page based on the server's response.
```

Therefore, a standard form submit will always incur a page reload.

However, you can use AJAX to make your HTTP request, which allows you to avoid a page reload.

Have a look at [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

The default action after submit is to send to the page where it manipulates the data. if you are trying to stop the refresh, i.e you are not submitting the form.

1. stop the form from default submitting using `e.preventDefault()`. this will stop the default submit behavior, which includes reload of page[ but form is not submitted]
2. you have to submit the form using **AJAX** in background [your data is submitted in the background to the required page]